# onerror display none - php ($.row['img'])

Tags: php, html, error-handling

I am hoping someone can help. I have been using [ onerror=this.style.display="none"] and for some reason it just stopped working. I can't seem to get it to work again. Does anyone know an alternative to the below solution?

```
<img class="basicimg" src='.$row['anncimg'].' onerror=this.style.display="none"></img>
```

Comment: Yeah, I had already tried your edit below, it still shows the broken image.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a function,

```
<img class="basicimg" src=“<?php echo $row['anncimg'] ?>” 
    onerror="SomeFun(this)">





<script>
   function SomeFun(ele) {
       $(ele).style.display="none"
   }

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the top solution but it still shows the broken link.

Comment: Forgot to add echo statement Answer updated please check.

Answer (score 0):

So if I put in the width and height it doesn't show the broken image icon.

```
<img class="basicimg" src='.$row['anncimg'].' width="100%" height="250px" onerror=this.style.display="none"
```